# How do I calculate gradient?

Tags: functions, vector-analysis

$q(x)=x^TAx+b^Tx+c$
Where A is matrix,

$x,b\in \mathbb{R}^n $

$c\in \mathbb{R}$

So someone in my book wrote that q(x) is the same like $q(x)=a_{11}x_1^2+...a_{nn}x_n^2+2a_{12}x_1x_2...+2a_{ij}x_ix_j+  b_1x_1....b_nx_n + c$

Can someone explain me how they get that and what is that?
Thank you

Comment: Presumably the matrix $A$ is then symmetric ($A=A^T$) for otherwise the formula won't hold. Did you not cover real quadratic forms in linear algebra? This is rather standard stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Since your  $x$ and  $b$ are in  $\mathbb{R}^n$, then  you may write  $$x=\begin{bmatrix}  x_1 \\  x_2 \\ \vdots  \\ x_n\end{bmatrix},  \quad  b=\begin{bmatrix}  b_1 \\  b_2 \\ \vdots  \\ b_n\end{bmatrix}  $$

Then your $A$ is surely  an  $n \times  n$ matrix, and it  can be also written as  $$ A=\begin{bmatrix}  a_{11}  & a_{12}  & \cdots  & a_{1n}\\  a_{21}  & a_{22}  & \cdots  & a_{2n}\\  \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & 
\vdots    \\ a_{n1}  & a_{n2}  & \cdots  & a_{nn}\end{bmatrix} $$
Now try expanding your $q(x)$ you will get the desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla q(\boldsymbol{x})=
(\boldsymbol{A}+\boldsymbol{A}^{T})\, \boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{b}$